# KnockoutJS: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I use KnockoutJS in my app. Today I've got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined` in browser console and page doesn't load, although I'm loading Knockout plugin and recently everything worked fine.

plugins from `head`

```
<script src="/assets/my/libs/knockout-2.1.0.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/my/libs/knockout.mapping.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my javascript file

```
var IllustratorModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  window.komodel = this;
  this.pre_offerings = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

  ....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you add the knockout mapping plugin script tag before this code?

Comment: @GôTô I'm using Ruby on Rails framework and load `knockout.mapping.js` in my `application.js`. Added content of `head`

Comment: this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/259/

Comment: Look in the dev tools of your browser and verify the scripts are loaded

Comment: @RobertSlaney as I wrote in the question knockout scripts loaded fine

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is putting a breakpoint on the line of code an having a look at the state of the system.

Is your IllustratorModel "class" constructed as the script is executed by the browser, or are you deferring this until the onload/ready event.  You might be falling foul of asynchronous script loading

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem today.. and it ended up that knockout-{version}.js was referenced twice.